# Can you identify this video plug?

Tags: connector, identification

An analog video camera has this connector.

9.4mm, sting hole much thinner than in RCA (but still too thick for a copper core); has 2 bumps (or whatever they're called) on its sides (turning lock?). No screw thread.

[image]

Comment: It's BNC female

Comment: Also, the "turning lock" you refer to makes it a "bayonet-style" plug, which is what the B in BNC stands for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a female BNC connector. They're normally found on the front and back panels of devices like oscilloscopes that need a coaxial connection for good high-frequency response.

[image: Male and female BNC diagram]

Answer (score 6):

It's a [BNC female](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BNC_connector) connector. It may be 50 ohms or 75 ohms (50 ohms is more common for antennas and 75 for video).

The difference is not too important for the connector itself, but you should find out the proper impedance for the cable or you may compromise the video quality.